# Implementing Ajax - Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to implement ajax into when I favorite a place, but the reload/update of the section/ajax functionality doesn't work.  Only if I reload the page, then I see the action that has occurred.  Would appreciate any tips.

My **favorite_places/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="heart">
<p class="text-center">
   <% if current_user %>
     <%- unless current_user.favorite_places.exists?(id: @place.id) -%>
       <%= link_to favorite_places_path(place_id: @place), remote: true,   method: :post do %>
         <span title="Favorite this Place"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></i></span>
       <% end %>
     <%- else -%>
       <%= link_to favorite_place_path(@place), remote: true,  method: :delete do %>
         <span title="Un-Favorite this Place"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i></span>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
</p>
</div>
```

My **favorite_places_controller.rb**

```
  def update
   @favorite_place.update_attributes[params[:place]]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @place }
      format.js 
    end  
   end
```

My **update.js.erb**

```
<%  if @place.favorited %>
   $(' #<%= @place.id %>').html("true");
   console.log ("<%= @place.name %> has been favorited.");
<% else %>
   $(' #<%= @place.id %>').html("false");
   console.log ("<%= @place.name %> is not a favorite.");
<% end %>
```

My **dev console output**

```
DELETE http://0.0.0.0:3000/favorite_places/34 406 (Not Acceptable) 
 jquery.js?body=1:8716send     
 jquery.js?body=1:8716jQuery.extend.ajax 
 jquery.js?body=1:8146$.rails.rails.ajax 
 jquery_ujs.js?body=1:73$.rails.rails.handleRemote 
 jquery_ujs.js?body=1:149(anonymous function) 
 jquery_ujs.js?body=1:299jQuery.event.dispatch 
 jquery.js?body=1:5108elemData.handle
```

Comment: where is your div tag `<div id="<%= @place.id %>"></div>`? Regardless, you should see in the console logs of your browser's developers options some sort of output.

Comment: @kobaltz - I edited my question to add my console output and the div this is wrapped in, but am I supposed to have a place.id div?  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @kobaltz Do you want to run ajax call in delete function ?

Comment: @anusha - I'm trying to just have the heart refresh instead of the full page to show favorite/not favorited.

Comment: @phattiyo Ok, your console output shows you run delete function. try to run update function as you have written js for update function right

Comment: @anusha - <%= link_to favorite_place_path(@place), remote: true,  method: **:delete** do %>  -- I have tried **method: :update** in my **show** but that didn't work either.  Receive the same error.

Comment: @phattiyo I am not saying to change `method: :update` try to click on this link and check whether `update.js.erb` calls or not

Comment: @anusha - I don't see the call under "network" but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @phattiyo You see delete request in console because you clicked on the second link `<%= link_to favorite_place_path(@place), remote: true,  method: :delete do %>`. Sign in your app and then click on the link so it'll take you to the update method. On the second thought why do you have delete link for non signed in users? It doesn't make sense to allow a non signed in user to delete anything

Comment: @Mandeep - thanks, but I'm a bit lost.  I am signed in and there shouldn't be a delete for not-signed in users.  The delete is under the "unless..."  I have:  (1) if current user signed in, then (2) unless favorite exists, link to favorite place path else delete.  The favorite action should also create a favorite place in the database or else delete one.

Comment: @phattiyo Ahh my bad didn't pickup unless statement because of indentation, but it still doesn't make sense. If current user doesn't have a favourite place then what are you trying to delete? Can you post your destroy action with its js?

Comment: @phattiyo change these 2 lines `<%= link_to edit_favorite_place_path(place_id: @place), remote: true,   method: :post do %>`, `@favorite_place.update_attributes[params[:place_id]]` and try by clicking `update` method instead of `delete`

Comment: thanks @anusha - I tried that and it told me "undefined local variable or method for favorite_place".  I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: @phattiyo does your controller have the edit action, do you have this(`resources: favorite_places`) in your routes.rb file